# Force Keyboard visible in alert dialog box

Tags: android, keyboard, android-alertdialog

I would like to use an alert dialog where there are several edittexts, such that the users can type and then click the save button.

I have successfully inflated my alertdialog using my layout xml (the xml named as custom_dialog_add), code as follows:

```
   public OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
   // create a new Button and add it to the ScrollView   
   {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) 
      {   

          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null));
            builder.create();

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_add, null); 

            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, null);             
            AlertDialog Custom_dialog_add = builder.create();
            Custom_dialog_add.show();
```

The EditText and Button names inside the alert dialog say to be A_EditText, B_EditText and Button_Save.

> > How could I force the keyboard turn on / visible at all time when inside the alertdialog, no matter the EditTexts are focused or not?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(YOUREDITTEXTHERE, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

replace YOUREDITTEXTHERE with your EditText view

Answer (score 0):

After to show the dialog you should be able to `requestFocus()` on one of the `EditText`s and that should bring up the keyboard.